# Hide cursor on atom-shell application startup

Tags: macos, cursor, autostart, electron

Has anyone managed to create an atom-shell-based, kiosk-style application that hides the mouse cursor on startup? The app should autostart on login.

Pure JS/CSS doesn't seem to cut it so now I'm resorting to nasty hacks using Cursorcerer and Applescript.

Any clues?

Comment: Why does pure CSS not work? I added `cursor: none;` on the `BODY` tag of my CSS and the cursor went away. The only trick is making sure the body actually fills the window. For that you can use CSS or even javascript depending on how your contents are set up. I'm on node.js v0.11.14 and atom-shell 0.17.1.

Answer (score 0):

[Cursorcerer's 64-bit version](http://doomlaser.com/cursorcerer-hide-your-cursor-at-will) should now hide the cursor properly on startup if configured to without any AppleScript hacks necessary.